# tableSorter limitation (sort) one page at a time?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

i see that in tableSorter you can sort one page at a time which concerns me.

Only 1 page of results can be sorted at a time?, which is pretty limiting. If you have a query result that spans multiple pages, how you will handle this?

If anyone knows better, feel free to correct me if iam incorrect

Thanks.

Comment: For sorting data on multiple pages I have used my own sorting functions which do an AJAX-request with jQuery to the server and sort the data in SQL and filling the results with the data from the server. I think it is the best way to go - because doing it directly in jQuery would require you to load all the data you have divided in the pages, which may be fine if it is just a couple of pages, but becomes quite ineffective with larger data sets and is a bit against the principle of dividing the results into pages in the first place.

Comment: do you have sample code where i can see how you implement through ajax-requst?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assign an ID to the th in thead for the table which correspond to you columns in the  SQL-table.

```
$("table thead th").click(function(){
    $.getJSON('ajax/get_results.php', 
        {sortby: $(this).attr('id')},
        function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(){
                // fill table here
            }
        });   
});
```

You could create some function for sorting the table that you also could use for changing page with AJAX if you are not already doing it.

And on the backend then sort with SQL

```
"SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ".$_GET['sortby']
```

Of course you should secure that sortby, for example filter it with an array of allowed values. I would suggest creating an array with allowed column sort names and using the [array_intersect()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function to only filter out the allowed values or just check with

```
if(isset($allowed_columns[$_GET['sortby']]))
```

Then just output it all in JSON by putting all the results in an array and then:

```
echo json_encode($array_with_results);
```

I guess you would like to output somthing like this in JSON:

```
{
  {col1: 'row1',col2: 'row1',col3: 'row1'},
  {col1: 'row2',col2: 'row2',col3: 'row2'},
  {col1: 'row3',col2: 'row3',col3: 'row3'}
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i dont know php, have you by any chance done in asp.net?

Comment: Well, I don't know asp.net on the other hand. But the JavaScript would be the same and also MsSQL has ORDER BY. So you just need some function for creating the JSON. If ASP does not have it you could do it manually with a loop. But I think you can find some method here http://json.org/ or otherwise you can see the JSON structure on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example